# store jwt token into cookie in python flask restplust for login api

Tags: access-token, flask-restplus, pyjwt, flask-jwt-extended

I have written REST API for login and logout using flask-restplus and flask_jwt_extended, I implemented jwt access_token generation that works seamlessly, but now I need to store token into cookie.

my code is like this:

**api/user/resource.py**

```
from app.auth_helper import Auth
from flask_restplus import Resource
from flask import request

@user_api_ns.route("/login")
class LoginUser(Resource):
    post_data = request.json
    return Auth.login_user(data=post_data)
```

**auth_helper.py**

```
import datetime
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask import jsonify

def encode_auth_token(user):
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user, fresh=True, expires_delta=datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=5))

class Auth(object):
    @staticmethod
    def login_user(data):
        try:
            auth_token = encode_auth_token(data.get("username"))
            if auth_token:
               response_object = jsonify({'status': 'success', 'Authorization': auth_token.decode()})
               set_access_token(response_object, auth_token)
               return response_object, 200
        except Exception as er:
            print er
            return {"status": "fail"}, 401
```

But the above code gives me error:

```
TypeError: <Response 367 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable
```

if I do not use jsonify(..) I get error `dict object does not have set_cookie attribute` which is quite obvious as `set_access_cookie` is expecting a response object not a normal dict

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this,

```
response_object = jsonify({'status': 'success', 'Authorization': auth_token.decode()})
set_access_cookies(response_object, auth_token)
return response_object
```

because `jsonify` already return response object.